# Assembler i8080 Multiplying two 16bits numbers

Tags: assembly

I have to prepare program for i8080 processor. My program have to multiplying two 16b numbers. But I don't know how to check multiplier bit by bit.

e.g 1111 * 1011 = 
first bit of 1011  is 1 so I add 1111 
second bit is 1 so I add 11110
third bit is 0 so I don't add 111100
forth is 1 so I add 1111000

result is 1111+11110+1111000=10100101

And my only problem is how to chceck bits of multiplier?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to shift right and then check the carry, otherwise you have to keep changing which bit you test and that's hard, especially with a register pair. The shifting is however a bit annoying on 8080 since only `A` can be rotated. Let's say the multiplier is in `BC` (and the multiplicand in `HL` and the result in `DE` so you can shift the multiplicand with `DAD H` and it takes some `XCHG` to do the add-to-result but it happens less often)

```
mov a, b
ora a    ; reset carry
rar
mov b, a
mov a, c
rar
mov c, a
jnc skipadd
```

Using `ora a` ensures that the multiplier simply goes to zero, this allows an exit test such as:

```
mov a, b
ora c
jnz looptop
```

If you unroll by 16 you can just fill `BC` from the left with the carry from the left shift of the multiplicand, it won't make any difference.